# Nuxt "multiple accounts" login similar to Google

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, account, vue-apollo

I'm trying to implement an account switcher similar to what Google has:

[image: Google account switcher]

I'm wondering how they implement it; is it all on the client, using cookies/local storage?

I have a Nuxt app and am using Nuxt auth package.  I'm wondering what the best way to implement this multiple account switcher is.

I'm also using `vue-apollo` and assuming that I would `this.$apollo.getClient().clearStore()` after every switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nuxt-auth  custom schemes or local

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    login1: { /* ... */ },
    login2: { /* ... */ },
  }
}
```

use local or customschemes

**~/schemes/customScheme.js**

```
import { LocalScheme } from '~auth/runtime'

export default class CustomScheme extends LocalScheme {
  // Override `fetchUser` method of `local` scheme
  async fetchUser (endpoint) {
    // Token is required but not available
    if (!this.check().valid) {
      return
    }

    // User endpoint is disabled.
    if (!this.options.endpoints.user) {
      this.$auth.setUser({})
      return
    }
    
    // Try to fetch user and then set
    return this.$auth.requestWith(
      this.name,
      endpoint,
      this.options.endpoints.user
    ).then((response) => {
      const user = getProp(response.data, this.options.user.property)
      
      // Transform the user object
      const customUser = {
        ...user,
        fullName: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName,
        roles: ['user']
      }
      
      // Set the custom user
      // The `customUser` object will be accessible through `this.$auth.user`
      // Like `this.$auth.user.fullName` or `this.$auth.user.roles`
      this.$auth.setUser(customUser)

      return response
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.$auth.callOnError(error, { method: 'fetchUser' })
    })
  }
}
```

then your auth just add customscheme

```
 strategies: {
    login1: {
      scheme: '~/schemes/customScheme',
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

To login

```
this.$auth.loginWith('login1', { /* ... */ })
```

You can use local scheme or custom schemes

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local1: { scheme: 'local', /* ... */ },
    local2: { scheme: 'local', /* ... */ },
    custom: { scheme: '~/schemes/customStrategy', /* ... */ },
  }
}
```